# iOS UILabel cannot resize the text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, autoresize

I would like to implement the ULLabelExtended to autosize the text size of the UILabel to the device width. but when it comes to the execution; it shows the picture as the result instead of showing the full clause:

The full clause : Ze aangeplant cocos rond hun nieuwe home.

[image]

Are there any other alternatives to get the relationship or functions that  text size of label is proportional to the device width ?

The below is my code

Application:

```
 CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    [self.labelLong setWidthOfLabelWithMaxWidth:screenWidth];
    [self.labelShort setWidthOfLabelWithMaxWidth:screenWidth];
```

Source:

```
#import "UILabelExtended.h"



@implementation UILabelExtended
@synthesize selector,customDelegate, objectInfo;

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(self.selector)
        if([self.customDelegate respondsToSelector:self.selector]) {
            [self.customDelegate performSelector:self.selector withObject:self];
            return;
        }
}

- (void)dealloc {

    self.customDelegate = nil;
    self.selector = NULL;
    self.objectInfo = nil;
}
@end


@implementation UILabel(UILabelCategory)

- (void)setHeightOfLabel {
    UILabel* label = self;

    //get the height of label content
    CGFloat height = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width, 99999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
    //set the frame according to calculated height
    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    if([label.text length] > 0) {

        frame.size.height = height;
    }
    else {
        frame.size.height = 0;
    }
    label.frame = frame;
}


- (void)setWidthOfLabel {
    UILabel* label = self;

    //get the height of label content
    CGFloat width = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(99999, label.bounds.size.height) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].width;
    //set the frame according to calculated height
    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    if([label.text length] > 0) {

        frame.size.width = width+5;
    }
    else {
        frame.size.width = 0;
    }
    label.frame = frame;
}

- (void)setHeightOfLabelWithMaxHeight:(float)maxHeight {
    UILabel* label = self;

    //get the height of label content
    CGFloat height = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width, maxHeight) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
    //set the frame according to calculated height
    CGRect frame = label.frame;

    if([label.text length] > 0) {
        if (height > maxHeight) {
            frame.size.height = maxHeight;
        }
        else {
            frame.size.height = height;
        }

    }
    else {
        frame.size.height = 0;
    }
    label.frame = frame;
}

- (void)setWidthOfLabelWithMaxWidth:(float)maxWidth  {
    UILabel* label = self;

    //get the height of label content
    CGFloat width = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(99999, label.bounds.size.height) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].width;
    //set the frame according to calculated height
    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    if([label.text length] > 0) {

        if (width > maxWidth) {
            frame.size.width = maxWidth;
        }
        else {
            frame.size.width = width;
        }
    }
    else {
        frame.size.width = 0;
    }
    label.frame = frame;
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you tried `Autoshrink` property in `Attribute inspector`?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what your asking, what about the sizeToFit method on UIView?

Comment: I have used size to fit but the label cannot show all text in one line

Comment: Did you try this, by setting the numberOfLines property to Zero.. ?

Comment: Actually I need only one line to be displayed. Only by changing the font size is considered because of the design specification